# package event-service/internal/form is not in GOROOT

Tags: go, testing, package, go-packages

I am trying to run `go test -v -cover -race -tags=integration_tests ./...` but it gives me the following error: `package event-service/internal/form is not in GOROOT`

**GOPATH**=`"/home/user/go"`

**GOROOT**=`"/usr/local/go"`

**GO Version**: `go1.17.5 linux/amd64`

Comment: did you forgot to init `go mod` inside of the root package directory?

Comment: You tagged this with `glide`. If you are trying to use that, `glide` is no longer maintained and cannot work with many existing modules.

Comment: @OlegButuzov No, I did it

Comment: @JimB Oh, It's just mistake